# I am trying to update a field inside a document in Firestore from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a field inside a document in firestore from reactjs and its showing an error, even though others did it and it worked for them.

[image: my code]

[image: error]

app.js

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
export { auth, app, db };
```

postpage.js

```
import { auth, app, db } from "../../firebase/config";
import { collection,  getDocs,  addDoc,  deleteDoc,  doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const [allPosts, setPosts] = useState([]);

 const likePost = async (id, likes) => {
 await updateDoc(doc(db, "posts", id), {
   likes: likes + 1,
 });
};

  const getPosts = async () => {
   const data = await getDocs(postsControllerRef);
   setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id 
  })));
  setLoading(false);
 };

return(
{allposts.map((post, index) => (
 <button 
  onClick={() =>
   likePost(post.postid, post.likes)
  }
 >Like</button>
))}
)
```

Comment: Hello, please add your code as text and not images. Also do share your complete code so we can see what the issue could be. Here either `db` or `id` seems to be `undefined` but we cannot see  where those values are coming from.

Comment: The `db` looks fine your code. Can you please confirm where the `allPosts` arrays is coming from? Best to `console.log(id, likes)` at the start of your `likePost` function and check if it is defined.

Comment: Consider using the [atomic increment operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) instead of adding `+1` in the application code to the value you read (as that value may be outdated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` is a number but `doc()` function takes only string path segments. Also, you must pass the `documentId` to update a specific document. Try changing the following line:

```
onClick={() =>
 likePost(post.id, post.likes) // pass .id and not .postid
}
```

If `postid` is the document ID itself, then try:

```
const likePost = async (id, likes) => {
  await updateDoc(doc(db, "posts", String(id)), {
    likes: likes + 1,
  });
};
```

Also, as @FrankVanPuffelen commented, you can use [`increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) instead as shown below:

```
import { increment } from "firebase/firestore"

await updateDoc(doc(db, "posts", String(id)), {
  likes: increment(1),
});
```